# Adding rows in a list in R

Tags: r

Consider the following code, that solves a system of DE such as Lotka–Volterra. It stores the solution in a list called "out" for 4 different cases. I have 2 questions:

(1) How can I calculate the sum of rows at each time step for 4 cases and store into a vector? I tried to use,  `apply(out[[i]][,1:2],1,sum)` but it produces an error as follows

Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (list) of

(2) Can you please explain the structure of output? and why it is not working while it works with matrices. I tried to create a similar list using random numbers, but could no reproduce the similar structure.

Thanks.

```
rm(list=ls())
library("foreach")
library("deSolve")
library(doParallel)
cl<-makeCluster(2, outfile = "debug.txt")
registerDoParallel(cl)

CASES = 4

LVmod <- function(Time, State, Pars) {
   with(as.list(c(State, Pars)), {
         Ingestion    <- rIng  * Prey * Predator
         GrowthPrey   <- rGrow * Prey * (1 - Prey/K)
         MortPredator <- rMort * Predator

        dPrey        <- GrowthPrey - Ingestion
        dPredator    <- Ingestion * assEff - MortPredator

        return(list(c(dPrey, dPredator)))
   })
   }

   solveODE<-function(times, LVmod, pars, yini, CASES){
   output<-foreach(x=1:CASES, .packages=c('deSolve'))  %dopar%
{
      if (x<CASES) ode(yini[[x%%CASES]], times, LVmod, pars)
      else         ode(yini[[CASES]], times, LVmod, pars)

 }
  }
     pars  <- c(rIng   = 0.2,    # /day, rate of ingestion
       rGrow  = 1.0,    # /day, growth rate of prey
       rMort  = 0.2 ,   # /day, mortality rate of predator
       assEff = 0.5,    # -, assimilation efficiency
       K      = 10)     # mmol/m3, carrying capacity

yini<-list()
yini[[1]]<-c(Prey = 1, Predator = 2)
yini[[2]]<-c(Prey = 5, Predator = 5)
yini[[3]]<-c(Prey = 2, Predator = 3)
yini[[4]]<-c(Prey = 4, Predator = 2)


out<-list()
for (i in 1:CASES) out[[i]]<-list()


for (i in 0:20){
   times <- seq(10*i, 10*(i+1), by = 1)

 output<-solveODE(times, LVmod, pars, yini, CASES)

 for (j in 1:CASES){
  out[[j]]<-rbind(out[[j]],output[[j]])
  ic11<-out[[j]][length(out[[j]][,1]),2]
  ic12<-out[[j]][length(out[[j]][,1]),3]
  yini[[j]]  <- c(Prey = as.numeric(ic11), Predator = as.numeric(ic12))
 }
```

}

```
  stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `lapply` instead of `apply` to loop through `list` elements; for example, to calculate the sum of values in the second column `Prey` for every list element you can do:

   ```
   lapply(out, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x[, 2])))
   #[[1]]
   #[1] 468.3304
   #
   #[[2]]
   #[1] 461.0533
   #
   #[[3]]
   #[1] 464.6915
   #
   #[[4]]
   #[1] 469.421
   ```
2. As for your second question: *"Can you please explain the structure of output?"* Well, considering that this is *your* code, that really is something *you* should know, isn't it. According to your code, you are constructing a `list` of `list`s:

   ```
   out<-list()
   for (i in 1:CASES) out[[i]]<-list()
   ```

PS. You really should format your code properly. Use proper indentations, align matching brackets, etc. It will make your code a lot easier to read!

---

### Update

If you want to calculate the sum of `Prey` and `Predator` for every `time`, you can use `rowSums` inside `lapply`:

```
lst <- lapply(out, function(x) rowSums(as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(x), ncol = 3))[, 2:3]))
```

`as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(x), ncol = 3))` converts your `list` into a `data.frame`.

You can column-bind the `list` entries using `cbind`:

```
df <- do.call(cbind, lst));
head(df);
#         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
#[1,] 3.000000 10.000000 5.000000 6.000000
#[2,] 3.490136  9.051351 5.445284 7.034600
#[3,] 4.359623  8.130653 5.915932 7.644949
#[4,] 5.467660  7.246250 6.317925 7.842548
#[5,] 6.517990  6.444182 6.589044 7.730863
#[6,] 7.255411  5.759818 6.711389 7.420815
```

The rows correspond to the different `time` values, the columns to the different `CASES`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It calculates the sum of all Prey population. But I want to calculate the the sum of population at each time step, i.e for t = 1, I need to calculate sum of  Predator+Prey for all 4 cases then for t=2, 3 ....., additionally, I also want to store the results in a column vector.

Comment: @bell So just calculate the sum of Predator+Prey. I gave you an example illustrating the use of `lapply`. I don't know what the problem is. I don't understand what you mean by "*I also want to store the results in a column vector*". Which results? You can bind list entries using e.g. `do.call(rbind.data.frame, your_list)`.

Comment: This is what I am trying, is it efficient? I am also getting error when try to insert time. I don't know, how to enter code in comments.  simMat<-matrix(0,nrow=length(out[[1]][,1]),ncol=2)
simMat[,1]<-lapply(out[[1]],"[",1) #insert time

for (count in 1:length(out[[1]][,1]))
  simMat[count,2]<-sum(unlist(lapply(out,"[",count,2:3),use.names = FALSE))

Comment: @bell I have edited&updatd my solution. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks Maurits. It is very helpful, One last thing, what is the efficient way of finally getting sum of each row in above table. I would like to have result in two columns where first column with time and second column with sum of rows.

Comment: @bell Not sure what you mean. `df` in my updated solution gives you the sum of `Prey` and `Predator` for every time (rows) for every `CASES` (columns). If you want to sum across all `CASES` you can do a simple `rowSums(df)`, i.e. `cbind.data.frame(time = seq(1:nrow(df)), sum = rowSums(df))`.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for help.